# Perimeter of an obtuse-angled triangle with area $10cm^2$ and longest side $10cm$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, maxima-minima

> What is the maximum and minimum perimeter of an obtuse-angled triangle with area $10cm^2$   and longest side $10cm$?

I have tried using $20= ab \sin C $ and $100=a^2+b^2+2ab \cos C $ but I am not getting the answer.

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Think geometrically instead of trig. Let the long side be the base, and think of all the possible places where the third point could be.

Comment: @Arthur's hint is the best, but you can express the area in terms of the sides and semiperimeter using Heron's formula, which you can get by keeping your expressions general and using $\cos^2 C+\sin ^2 C=1$. However this gives relatively little insight.

Comment: Let $AB=10$.  Then $C$ must lie inside the Thales circle over $AB$.  Furthermore its distance from $AB$ must be $2$ ...

Comment: Hence there can't be a maximum unless you regard a right angle as obtuse.  A supremum exists btw.

Comment: So we have to determine the point C$_{s}$ where the parallel line of distance 2 intersects the Thales circle. And then the distance of C$_s$ to A and B.

Comment: C$_s$ = ($\sqrt{21}$;2).

Comment: Should give $10+2\sqrt{35} \approx 21.8$.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @MichaelHoppe we need to determine one intersection C$_{sup}$ of the line $y=2$ with the Thales circle of $r=5$ around (0|0) the centre of [AB] wich we place onto the $x$-axis. The circumference $u_{sup} $of ABC$_{sup}$, then is the supremum of the   circumferences of all possible triangles ABC, which lie all inside the Thales circle. The right intersection point forms a rectangular triangle with hypothenuses of 5 and one side length of 2, consequentially the $y$-coordinate of C$_{sup}$ is $\sqrt{5^2 - 2^2}=\sqrt{21}$. Then we need the distances of this point C$_{sup} = (\sqrt{21}|2)$ to A$=(5|0)$ and B=$(-5|0)$. That is $\sqrt{\sqrt{(5-\sqrt{21})^2 + 4}}$ and $\sqrt{\sqrt{(5+\sqrt{21})^2 + 4}}$, respectively, the sum of which is equal $\sqrt{140}$. Yielding $$u_{sup}=\sqrt{140}+10=10+2\sqrt{35}\approx 21.8$$ The infimum is yielded for C$_{inf}=(0|2)$, which is $$u_{inf}=10+2\sqrt{29}\approx20.8$$